# Sub-directory or sub-domain for blog?

Tags: seo, blog, cms, content

I am working on an e-commerce website (written in ASP.NET MVC). I want to build a blog for my website to create some content and improve the Search Engine Ranking of the website/

I can think of 2 options for the blog domain:

- my-site.com/blog
- blog.my-site.com

Which option is recommended? Appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Related question: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/add-blog-to-existing-website/8371

Comment: Please edit your Post to ask only a single question so that it can be reopened.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Thanks, I have made it one question

Comment: Your question "Subdomain or subdirectory for a blog?" is so much discussed over the web that you must [read extensively](https://www.google.com/search?q=subdomain+or+subdirectory+for+a+blog) and make up your mind considering your very own priorities (IMHO, either one or the other has little impact on SEO, I chose subdomain for simplicity). As for the possibility to set up a hosted blogging platform on a subdomain, I find the question interesting and doesn't know the answer yet.

Comment: @Éric: thanks for your comment...

Comment: @HoomanBahreini, you're welcome. After reading [this](https://matt-stannard.blogspot.com/2013/02/blogger-in-subdirectory-of-my-domain.html) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/499127/setup-custom-domain-with-folder-in-path-for-blogger-hosted-blog), it seems that setting up a hosted blogging platform, like *Blogger* or *Medium*, on a subdirectory is possible but not straightforward.